# Excel: How to create a new value based on the first character and last 4 characters of cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I'm trying to come up with a single cell formula solution in excel.

The numbers in a column are 5 digits and start with a 4 or a 7.

Q: Depending on whether they start with a 4 or a 7, the number must be converted in another column to reflect letters replacing the 4 or 7.

example: cell A1 contains 41234 so I want B1 to automatically convert it to AA1234 and cell A2 contains 71234 and B2 should reflect BB1234

Is this doable without using macros? maybe a long formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example, try:

```
=CHOOSE(FIND(LEFT(A1),"47"),"AA","BB")&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)
```

Comment: This is great! just curious though how the "47" works in the logic if you're up for explaining.

Comment: The `FIND` looks for the first number in your cell  and returns its position in the string "47". if it's 4, it returns 1; if it's 7, it returns 2; anything else it returns an error. `CHOOSE` then uses this number (1 or 2) to choose between "AA" and "BB", respectively. Also, I just noticed that `LEFT(A1,1)` can be simplified to just `LEFT(A1)`. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
=choose(--left(a1), "", "", "", "AA", "", "", "BB")&mid(a1, 2, len(a1))
```

Comment: Might be better to use `NA()` rather than `""` so invalid entries through an error rather than a potentially invalid result.  Op didn't specify required exception handling, so might be moot.

Comment: @chrisneilsen - valid point but I'll let the OP decide so please leave your comment. My primary purpose for choosing this method was to show the OP how to easily add additional substitutions.

Answer (score 2):

I think I like CHOOSE better, but my Excel-fu is lacking.  This is an alternative
 `=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="4",CONCAT("AA",RIGHT(A1,4)),IF(LEFT(A1,1)="7",CONCAT("BB",RIGHT(A1,4))))`

Comment: Instead of `CONCAT("AA",RIGHT(A1,4))` you could have `"AA"&RIGHT(A1,4)`, which looks marginally nicer.

Comment: using concatenation in other software a lot it's easy to forget the simpler combinations..hehe

Answer (score 2):

Another version:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1)="4","AA",IF(LEFT(A1)="7","BB",""))&RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-1)
```